# Immediately updating a color variable upon selection from a ComboBox

Tags: java, swing

The assignment asks for a super class Shape and two subclasses Circle and Square.

I am to create an applet for selecting a shape (circle or square), size, and color from three separate JComboBox.

Every time the user clicks on the canvas, an object of the Shape class should be created according to the selections in the ComboBoxes and stored in an ArrayList to be printed out.

There is some sort of "lag" on the updating of the color variable. Every time I make a selection from the ComboBox associated with updating the color and go back to click on the canvas, a shape is printed with the previously selected color and THEN the next shape printed is the appropriately updated color.

Here is a look at the code:

```
    public class WholePanel extends JPanel
{
   private Color currentColor;
   private int size = 10;
   private Shape shape;
   private String SHAPE = "Circle";
   private String SIZE, CURRENTCOLOR;
   private CanvasPanel canvas;
   private JPanel topPanel, topSplitPanel;
   private JButton undo;
   private ArrayList <Shape>shapeList;
   private JComboBox shapeCombo, sizeCombo, colorCombo;

   public WholePanel()
   {
      //default color to draw is black 

      shapeList = new ArrayList();

      // label for displaying what to input
      Label label1 = new Label("Choose Circle or Square, its size, and its color.");

  // new button to undo last task
  undo = new JButton ("Undo");

  // combo box for selecting shape
  String[] circleSquare = {"Circle", "Square"};
  shapeCombo = new JComboBox(circleSquare);


  //combo box for selecting size
  String[] sizezzz = {"10","20","30","40","50"};
  sizeCombo = new JComboBox(sizezzz);


  //combo box for selecting color
  String[] colores = {"black","red","blue","green","orange"};
  colorCombo = new JComboBox(colores);


  // panel for displaying the three combo boxes and the undo button
  topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  topPanel.add(shapeCombo);
  topPanel.add(sizeCombo);
  topPanel.add(colorCombo);
  topPanel.add(undo);

  // new panel with grid layout for displaying label above panel including combo boxes
  topSplitPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
  topSplitPanel.add(label1);
  topSplitPanel.add(topPanel);

  // creates new object of CanvasPanel
  canvas = new CanvasPanel();

  // add ActionListeners to the undo button and each of JComboBox
  undo.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
  shapeCombo.addActionListener (new ComboListener());
  sizeCombo.addActionListener (new ComboListener());
  colorCombo.addActionListener (new ComboListener());

  //adds mouse listener to the canvas
  MouseListener pointListener = new PointListener();
  canvas.addMouseListener(pointListener);


 JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, topSplitPanel, canvas);
 setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  add(sp);
}

  //CanvasPanel is the panel where shapes will be drawn
  private class CanvasPanel extends JPanel
   {

  //this method draws all shapes 
  public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
   {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

       /*for(int i=0; i<shapeList.size(); i++)
        {
            shape = shapeList.get(i);
            shape.draw(page);
        }*/
       for (Shape shapee : shapeList)
        {
            shapee.draw(page);
        }


   }     
} //end of CanvasPanel class


   //ButtonListener defined actions to take in case

     //"Undo" is chosen.
   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
  {
      shapeList.remove(shapeList.size()-1);
  }
} // end of ButtonListener


   // listener class to set the color chosen by a user using
   // color combo box, set the size chosen using size combo box
   // or set the shape (circle or square) using shape combo box
   private class ComboListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
      if(event.getSource()==shapeCombo)
      {
          SHAPE = (String) shapeCombo.getSelectedItem();
      }
      if(event.getSource()==sizeCombo)
      {
          SIZE = (String) sizeCombo.getSelectedItem();
          if (SIZE.equals("10")){ size =10;}
          if (SIZE.equals("20")){ size =20;}
          if (SIZE.equals("30")){ size =30;}
          if (SIZE.equals("40")){ size =40;}
          if (SIZE.equals("50")){ size =50;}
      }
      if(event.getSource()==colorCombo)
      {
          CURRENTCOLOR = (String) colorCombo.getSelectedItem();
          if(CURRENTCOLOR.equals("black")){currentColor = Color.black;}
          if(CURRENTCOLOR.equals("red")){currentColor = Color.red;}
          if(CURRENTCOLOR.equals("blue")){currentColor = Color.blue;}
          if(CURRENTCOLOR.equals("green")){currentColor = Color.green;}
          if(CURRENTCOLOR.equals("orange")){currentColor = Color.orange;}
      }

     }
} // end of ComboListener


   // listener class that listens to the mouse
   public class PointListener implements MouseListener
{
 //in case that a user presses using a mouse,
 //record the point where it was pressed.
 public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event)
  {
     int X = event.getX();
     int Y = event.getY();

     if (SHAPE.equals("Square"))
     {
         shapeList.add(new Square(X-(size/2),Y-(size/2),size,currentColor));
     }

     if (SHAPE.equals("Circle"))
     {
         shapeList.add(new Circle(X-(size/2),Y-(size/2),size,currentColor));
     }
  }
 public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent event) {}
 public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent event) {}
 public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent event) {}
 public void mouseExited (MouseEvent event) {}

} // end of PointListener

} // end of Whole Panel Class
```

Comment: `It's as if there is some sort of "lag" on the updating of the color variable.` - Well don't guess. Test your theory. Add debug code to your class. Display the value of the variables in question before/after the various methods are invoked. Not related to your problem by for your PointListener class you can extend MouseAdapter, then you only need to implement the method that you want to handle. Also, checking the source of an event in a listener is not a good design. Create a unique listener for each component.

Comment: How would I go about creating a unique listener for each component? And it's just that no lag exists for the other variables that are being updated in the same manner as the color is

Comment: `How would I go about creating a unique listener for each component?` - Seriously?  Now you create a "ComboListener". Why can't you create a "ShapeComboListener" and a "SizeComboListener" etc?  `no lag exists for the other variables that are being updated in the same manner as the color is` - well something is different, which is why you need to do basic debugging. This is what programming is about. If the code was the same, then it would work the same. We can't test your code, that is your job. I gave you advice on how to do basic debugging.